# wagtail 'your first site': how do I link to original of gallery image?

Tags: wagtail

In the [getting started tutorial](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/getting_started/tutorial.html) for wagtail there is the following code in a template:

```
{% for item in page.gallery_images.all %}
    <div style="float: left; margin: 10px">
        {% image item.image fill-320x240 %}
        <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Please excuse me if I'm missing something obvious but I can't find out how to do this in the docs. How would I link to the original file? eg:

```
  <a href="WHAT_GOES_HERE_SO_I_CAN_DOWNLOAD_ORIGINAL_IMAGE?">{% image item.image fill-320x240 %}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `{{ img.url }}` property in your template.

```
{% for item in page.gallery_images.all %}
    <div style="float: left; margin: 10px">
        {% image item.image fill-320x240 as img %}
        <p>{{ item.caption }}</p>
        {% comment %}
            Assign your image `as img` (doesn't need to be `img`, you can
            use any alias you'd like
        {% endcomment %}
        <img href="{{ img.url }}" alt="{{ img.alt }}" />
        <a href="{{ img.url }}">This is the link to your image</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

By assigning your image an alias, such as `as img` (in the code above) you can use `{{ img.property_name }}` in your template.

Comment: Thanks very much. Here's what I ended up using:

`{% image item.image original as img %} <a href="{{ img.url }}">{% image item.image fill-320x240 %}</a>`